# autocomplete dynamic list with html formatted text

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html, dom

I want to generate autocomplete suggestion list with html formatted text like we while typing in google maps

[image]

and when i select one of the items in list i want my JavaScript to run with the text value so far i am only able to create a suggestion list but i get an arrow
[image]

which i don't want and have no clue how to add onclick action on each of text field.

Here is the code snippet of my somewhat working code
**javascript**

```
        var suggestlist = "datalist1";
        var list = document.getElementById(suggestlist);
        // As long as datalist has a child node, remove it
        while (list.hasChildNodes()) {   
            list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
        }

        for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
            var node = document.createElement("option");
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(response.results[i].title);
            node.appendChild(textNode);
            document.getElementById(suggestlist).appendChild(node);
        }
```

**html**

```
    <form>
    <div class="input-field" style="width: 30%">
        <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
        <input id="getlocation_pickup" placeholder="pickup location" type="search" list="datalist1" required
               onkeypress="placesSearch(platform, 'pickup')">
        <datalist id="datalist1"></datalist>
    </div>
```

Here is the link to [jsfiiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p31yx27q/) for the implemented code

if anyone can suggest me how to implement the google map like dynamic list, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: Because you are creating "option", so you are getting arrow of drop down. To avoid arrow just use 
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

Comment: can you be more specific what exactly should i edit since I am new to javascript

Comment: select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
} you can use this CSS. If it works for you then I will post this as an answer for others.

Comment: added 
    <style>
    select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
    </style>
but not working...

Comment: You have to add this css on run time. as you are creating option on run time. You can add it in jQuery code where you are creating options.

Comment: There is a hack also :  input:-webkit-autofill { background: #fff !important; } or select:-webkit-autofill { background: #fff !important; }

Comment: took me time to figure out what exactly to do but yeah adding elements inside `<select id="datalst"> </select> ` worked and making select display:none

if you can tell me how to add javascript  on selecting any of the list items it will be really helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135170/discussion-between-warl0ck-and-deep).